# Calling API in useEffect hook doesn't work correctly on prop update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm looking for feedback on this customer React hook. I'm wondering:

1. Does this look like a proper use of custom React hooks?
2. Is there a better way to switch between different API endpoints based upon the prop that is passed in? I'm looking to do something like:

```js
<MovieGrid typeOfMovies={"popular"} />

and

<MovieGrid typeOfMovies={"upcoming"} />
```

3. Do you have *any* feedback or recommendations on anything you see. Thank you!

The code I've provided does indeed work. But since hooks a relatively new I don't feel totally confident I'm using them right.

Here's what I've got:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function useFetchMovies(typeOfMovies) {
  const [movieData, setMovieData] = useState([]);


  const movieEndpointURL = () => {
    if (typeOfMovies === "upcoming") {
      return `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/upcoming?api_key={API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1&region=US`;
    } else if (typeOfMovies === "popular") {
      return `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key={API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1&region=US`;
    }
  };

  const fetchMovieData = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(movieEndpointURL());
      const movies = await res.json();
      setMovieData(movies.results);
      console.log(movies.results);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMovieData();
  }, []);

  return [movieData, setMovieData];
}

export { useFetchMovies };
```

Comment: Does this actually `fetchMovieData` when `typeOfMovies` change ? It looks to me the current use of useEffect would fetch after first render (like old `componentDidMount`) and not on prop changes later.

Comment: @Jokester, you know what, you're totally right. It doesn't update. Hmmmm.

Comment: I recommend [this article](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) to understand the new hook APIs (and the ideas behind them) :)

Comment: including [typeOfMovies] in useEffect should make it work when the prop changes

Comment: @jokester thank you so much for the recommended article. I just finished reading the article! It was a long read, but SO helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `useFetchMovies` seems to be correct expect the part that when `typeOfMovies` changes new data will not be fetched because when the useEffect first runs on mount of component it will refer to the `fetchMoviesData` that was initially created along with its closure and when the `useFetchMovies` hook is called again a new function is created which isn't referenced by the `useEffect`.

In order to make it word correctly you should pass `typeOfMovies` as the second argument to `useEffect` like

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchMovieData();
}, [typeOfMovies]);
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much for the feedback and kindness. It's all starting to make sense.

Comment: Do you think using the IF statements to switch between API endpoints is fine? Or would a switch statement or something else be preferred?

Comment: you don't actually need if statments you could simply do it using dynamic evaluation like `\`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${typeOfMovies}?api_key={API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1&region=US\`;`